# What's the best way to migrate from manual upgrades to composer updates?

Tags: 8, composer

I have an 8.9.19 installation that I would like to move over to use composer.

What's the best way to migrate the installation to use composer upgrades?  Manual installations are becoming a real pain.

Comment: You need to use the Composerizer project. https://github.com/grasmash/composerize-drupal

Comment: That does it. Please post that as an answer when you can so I may mark it solved by you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common way to 'flip' a project from not having Composer managed dependencies to being managed by Composer is to use the Composerize project: https://github.com/grasmash/composerize-drupal

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say there is a most common way. Drupal is by default now composer ready since it introduced two project templates of its own. The answer depends on the specific requirements. If you want to switch between different composer templates it's also no problem to start a new composer project, require the packages of the installed modules and then move database and files directory from the old to the new installation.

See https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/starting-a-site-using-drupal-composer-project-templates